# How to fix Mongoose deprecation warning about "strictQuery"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, deprecation-warning

When I start build my backend server, I get this deprecation warning, but it's showing that I'm connected to the database.

##### File *server.js*

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

##### File *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "backend",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

And this is the Mongoose deprecation warning:

[Screenshot of Mongoose Deprecation Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9HL.png)

It shows:

```
[MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. 
Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. 
Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: im sorry, this is the warning  => (node:21244) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.

Comment: what is your mongoDB url can you post it to ?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's a pid

Answer (score 34):

This warning was introduced to notify users about the change that will be introduced in Mongoose 7 to the default value of `strictQuery`.
It's default value will be brought back to `false`.

You can either set the `strictQuery` option to `true` globally to suppress the warning with:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
```

Or, set the flag to `false` if you want to override the current `strictQuery` behavior and prepare for the new release:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
```

Either way the warning should disappear.

For more information on why `strictQuery` will be brought back to `false` by default see [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11861).
For more information on `strictQuery` see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Add mongoose.set('strictQuery', false); before connecting to the MongoDB server.

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

Comment: *"where you user connecting the MongoDB server"* seems incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75002130/edit)?

Comment: What does this add over the most upvoted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74713539/2308683

Comment: @PeterMortensen this is just a warning.
Even though you are getting this warning your mongo db will connect and work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Network Access* on your MongoDB page in the browser. Then click button <kbd>Add IP address</kbd> and add address "0.0.0.0".

It helps you to connect.

Comment: The deprecation notice has nothing to do with allowed clients or any server config. Also, the warning happens without using Atlas or any cloud hosted Mongo

Answer (score 0):

> Mongoose supports a separate strictQuery option to avoid strict mode for query filters. This is because empty query filters cause Mongoose to return all documents in the model, which can cause issues.

Provide mongoose.set('strictQuery',true); to solve your issue

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I added `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)` then the message went away.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75191440/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed the image since the line of code is all that's necessary... What does this add over the most upvoted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74713539/2308683

Answer (score -2):

You can try it...

```
const dbSetup = async () => {
  try {
    const DBURL = process.env.DB_URL;
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose.connect(DBURL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      ssl: true,
      sslValidate: false,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Databse Connection Error : " + err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).