# MongoDB not working properly , error shows in window with VS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code, mongoose

[MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Please help me out to get it resolve

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74713539/13211263..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix Mongoose Deprecation Warning "the strictQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711770/how-to-fix-mongoose-deprecation-warning-the-strictquery)

Answer (score 0):

Added deprecation warning https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/12675. Just add mongoose.set before your mongoose.connect to suppress the warning.

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

mongoose.connect(// codes)
```